# Window positions and sizes

Tags: macos, applications

Most questions I've seen look for exactly the opposite thing, but what I want is to always open an app in its default position and size. I don't want its layout saved on quit. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Presumably without asking the application developer?  How is macOS supposed to know what the default size and position are for application X?

Comment: It always knows. All the defaults are stored either in the defaults database, and a new record is created for every app you install. And as soon as you open and change something, a plist file is created with your preferences for the app, such as login info and yes, the size and position. I want to always use the defaults database for the size and position